# I can't send mail using PHPMailer in Laravel

Tags: php, phpmailer, laravel-8

I am trying to send mail to reset password. But I faced one problem.
I used laravel, and I am using phpmailer to send mail.
However, mail is not sent. Time out error happens.

My code is as follow:

```
    $mail = new PHPMailer(true);

    try {
        $mail->SMTPDebug = 2;
        $mail->isSMTP();
        $mail->Host       = 'smtp.gmail.com;';
        $mail->SMTPAuth   = true;
        $mail->Username   = 'myemail@gmail.com';
        $mail->Password   = 'mypassword';
        $mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';
        $mail->Port       = 587;

        $mail->setFrom('myemail@gmail.com', 'My name');
        $mail->addAddress($request->email);

        $mail->isHTML(true);
        $mail->Subject = 'Reset Password';
        $mail->Body    = 'HTML message body in <b>'.$token.'</b> ';
        $mail->AltBody = 'Body in plain text for non-HTML mail clients';
        $mail->send();
        echo "Mail has been sent successfully!";
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        echo "Message could not be sent. Mailer Error: {$mail->ErrorInfo}";
    }
```

The errors like this:

```
2021-08-03 13:29:47 SMTP ERROR: Failed to connect to server: Connection timed out (110)
Invalid hostentry:
SMTP connect() failed. https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Troubleshooting
Message could not be sent. Mailer Error: SMTP connect() failed. 
https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Troubleshooting
```

If you have the solution, please answer for me!
Thanks.

Comment: `'smtp.gmail.com;'` - remove the semi-colon on the host name inside the string.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/66185343/642096

Comment: Does this answer your question? [PHP Mailer returns PHP Fatal error: Uncaught PHPMailer\PHPMailer\Exception: SMTP Error: Could not authenticate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66184687/php-mailer-returns-php-fatal-error-uncaught-phpmailer-phpmailer-exception-smtp)

Comment: This sounds like your hosting provider is blocking outbound SMTP. Check that using the advice in the PHPMailer troubleshooting guide, and then perhaps contact your hosting provider to get the block removed.